# Angular material table with sticky header

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using angular7 with Angular material design templates. Currently, my result is as follows, 
[image]

But I want my result is as follows. Scrollbar under sticky header.

[image]

I put some demo code and [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8fuwbr) as your reference.

**HTML**

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">

    <!-- Position Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Weight Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Symbol Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
    <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.example-container {
  height: 400px;
  overflow: auto;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Its the default behavior of angular material tables. If you want scroll out side you need to make two separate tables or somehow you able to make scroll inside then your header and body cell aliment create problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like that using two table one for the header and another for the data. Please see the working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/sticky-column-header-2qry3k).

Comment: Be aware that this solution causes the headers to misalign, because the scrollbar doesn't take up space there.